# go back to previous commit make changes and push to the branch

Tags: git, github

i recently ran into an issue while resolving conflicts after git pull.
i couldn't resolve conflict properly as i am fairly new to git.
ihave following branches:

- pmp101
- staging
- master

i was working on staging branch.
before git pull i had already commited my code, so i decided to revert everything i was trying to do when trying to resolve conflicts.

so i did git log and did `git checkout [shaofmylastcommit]`. now i got my code back so the other developer whose code was the reason for conflict, he gave me his files which i replaced with mine and add my codes to it which i copied before replacing the file.

now i commited my code again but when i tried to git push it gave me an error saying you are at detached head which i didn't understand. so i thought i needed to be on my branch again to push the code, so i did `git checkout staging`

but now again all my changes were gone, which freaked me out. but i got a meaage saying "this is a good time to keep your changes to new branch as you are trying to switch branch" or something like that. so i did exactly and a i got a new branch with name "promotion".

now i did `git checkout promotion` and got my changes back(thank god! phew!)...

but now i have this new branch and i am supposed to work on branch "staging" so what should i do and if i run into similar problem in future what should i do, i am guessing there was no need for me to create a new branch i could have pushed those changes from branch "staging", but i was on detached head which i don't know what means exaclty.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked out the right commit, and see the right content, but the wrong branch, you can reset your staging branch to that commit:

```
git checkout staging
git reset --hard <yourCommit>
```

However, if the `git push` entails a `--force`, that might not be a good idea.

An alternative approach is to:

- reset your staging branch to origin/staging (that way, any new commit done on that branch will be simply pushed, without --force)

  ```
  git checkout staging
  git reset --hard origin/staging
  ```
- replay your commit (or two commits) on top of that branch:

  ```
  git cherry-pick <one-commit>  
  git cherry-pick <second-commit>
  ```

Then you can push normally.

Comment: Thanks for your help